# Incrementing a date in openrefine

Tags: openrefine

I have a date in format of `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss`

Please provide a GREL expression that increments date to 1 month from the present date value for all cells in the column in openrefine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to make sure the data in the cells is of type 'date' - if the text in the cell is in green then the data is already 'date' type. Otherwise you will need to convert it using the GREL:

```
value.toDate()
```

Screenshot - before converting to date

[image: dates in OpenRefine as String type]

Screenshot - after converting to date

[image: dates in OpenRefine as Date type]

Once you have the data as Date type, then you can use the following GREL to increment by one month:

```
value.inc(1,'month')
```

For more on using dates in OpenRefine see https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/GREL-Date-Functions

Comment: If it's green, it could also be a numeric value and not just a date.

Comment: That’s true in a general sense (and boolean values also render in green text), but in the context of the question which states “I have a date in the format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss” the text being in green can only indicate a date